# Android swiping

Tags: android, swipe

So, for a master-detail view, i can get swipe-based action working on specific views, such as the list items.  Yet, i want the user to swipe from the right of those (in the detail section, even though the detail section is filled with content).  Any ideas how to do that?  I tried putting a button with an invisible background color in the detail view's layout, and setting the swipe listener to that, but the actual content of the detail view seem to prevent such a button from having enough focus to accept the swipe action.  is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want a master detail layout with a ListView and a ViewPager.

The ListView you already have in the master fragment, the detail fragment will be a ViewPager.

Here is an example of a ViewPager being used for [Screen Slides](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html). If this is not what you mean then let me know and I will edit this answer.

Comment: the viewpager is for going between detail views.  i want a custom action, particularly to hide the list view.

Comment: It sounds you like want the ListView to be a [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) instead then.

Comment: kindof, but those are only for metadata (settings) normally